# Calling Jasper Report from external java web application

Tags: java, jasperserver

As I am new to jasperserver, I need help for calling reports in jasperserver from my external java web application by using restful webservices.

Could you give me some examples that show how that is done?

Comment: Take a look at this site, there is an example too.
http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/getting-started-rest-web-service-api